# Como funciona o "padding" do C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, struct, otimização, padding

Em várias respostas aqui no StackOverflow tenho percebido os usuários comentando sobre `padding` nas estruturas de dados.

```
struct {
  int a;
  char b;
  float d;
}
```

1. O que vem a ser este `padding` (enchimento) que existe entre os campos de uma `struct`?
2. Ele ocorre apenas em `structs` ou pode ocorrer em `classes` também?
3. Como posso evitá-lo? (Otimizar o código)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## O que é

Isto é usado para facilitar o trabalho de leitura de memória e colocação em registradores. Os registrados trabalham com um tamanho fixo de acordo com sua arquitetura. O ideal é que os dados caibam dentro deste tamanho. Então os dados são armazenados em [palavras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101). O *padding* (ou preenchimento) alinha estes dados acrescentando *bytes* não significativos. Os compiladores fazem isto por padrão. Se precisa de um comportamento específico é necessário o uso de diretivas indicando a forma necessária.

Para todos os efeitos classes são estruturas (`struct`s) e funcionam da mesma forma.

## Desperdício

No seu exemplo a estrutura provavelmente terá 12 *bytes* (arquitetura de 32 bits) já que o membro `b` será preenchido com 3 *bytes* extras para fazer o *padding*. Assim todos os membros terá 4 bytes. Este número é obtido levando em consideração que a maioria das arquiteturas possuem uma [palavra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) com 4 *bytes* de tamanho.

Evidentemente em arquiteturas 64 bits o estrago é ainda maior (e é possível ter preenchimento ainda maior), você pode ter até 7 *bytes* de desperdício. A palavra costuma refletir como os registrados são usados nos processadores. Note que estou usando dados comuns nas principais arquiteturas. Compiladores C e C++ são liberais quanto ao tamanho de quase todos os tipos se aplicando um tamanho mínimo.

Eliminar o *padding* pode otimizar em alguns casos o consumo de memória mas pode causar outros problemas de performance. Ler dados da memória em tamanhos diferentes da palavra da arquitetura precisam de processamento extra. Na maioria dos casos não compensa a troca.

## Economizando

Claro que há casos que podem haver o preenchimento natural mantendo o uso da palavra:

```
struct {
    int a;
    char b;
    char c;
    char d;
    char e;
    float f;
}
```

Esta estrutura pode muito bem ter os mesmo 12 *bytes*. Os 4 `chars` cabem no alinhamento da palavra. Então pensar a ordem dos membros pode ser bastante útil.

Esta é a forma mais recomendada de resolver o problema. Ele não possui nenhuma desvantagem para o software em si. Claro que eventualmente você terá que colocar dados em uma ordem que não é tão intuitiva para ler.

Mesmo neste caso você só terá uma vantagem de consumo de memória clara se a estrutura for usada repetidas vezes em outra estrutura. Economizar alguns *bytes* não vale o esforço. Economizar alguns *bytes* multiplicado por milhões de vezes **pode** fazer alguma diferença.

Mas também é possível controlar como o **padding** é feito com diretivas (muitas vezes não padronizadas entre compiladores). Exemplo:

Quando realmente precisa, podemos fazer o *packing*. Exemplos em empacotamento.

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

No C++ da Microsoft, como outros [compiladores que seguem o padrão do C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html),  torna o tamanho em 1 *byte* eliminando de fato qualquer *padding*. Claro que membros com mais de 1 byte terão seu tamanho normal. Isto indica o tamanho mínimo que o membro deve ter. No GCC poderia usar opcionalmente:

```
__attribute__((packed))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Packing.c).

Desta forma informa-se que um membro específico deve não receber o *padding*. Isto é mais flexível mas pode ser inseguro em certas plataformas.

Empacotar membros é arriscado e se não souber bem o que está fazendo poderá ter resultados inesperados. Bom, quase tudo em C e C++, mas alguns recursos são mais arriscados.

Mesmo a forma considerada padrão não é considerada portável.

Obviamente podemos usar o operador `sizeof` para descobrir o tamanho real do dado. Este operador devolve sempre o tamanho exato que o dado ocupa na memória e não a soma de seus membros. Ou seja, ele considera o preenchimento.

Reforço que raramente estes procedimentos são necessários. Quase sempre a tentativa de empacotar estruturas é otimização prematura. Por tornar o uso das estruturas menos intuitivo a recomendação é evitar até que se prove ser fundamental.

[Artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

[Artigo interessante](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/).

Comment: Vou aguardar a conclusão de sua resposta antes de votar, mas até o momento já deu uma ideia básica do que é

Comment: e como vc sabe que o `int` e o `float` tem 4 bytes cada e que o alinhamento de memória deva ser de 4 bytes? `__attribute__((packed))` é universal entre todos os compiladores?

Comment: @bigown, quando tiver tempo, favor conclua sua resposta, estou bastante interessado em ler ela.

Comment: @Kaminary me desculpe, estou com um problema de saúde e não posso ficar muito tempo fora da cama. Mas a página está aberta e enquanto eu não tirar o aviso, eu não vou desistir dela e vou melhorar.

Comment: @PequiAmarelo dei uma melhorada e vou melhorar mais assim que der. Eu não sei se tem 4 *bytes* eu acho que tem baseado no que as arquiteturas *mainstream* usam. Esse atributo não é universal, não desta forma. Vou melhorar mais esta parte ainda.

Comment: @bigown Sem problemas, não é uma pergunta mortal que necessite ser respondida em 1 dia ^^