# Tamanho da alocação de structs

Tags: c++, ponteiro, struct, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

Quando declaro uma variável normal, de tipo `int` por exemplo, o compilador vai lá e, dependendo da arquitetura, separa 4 *bytes*.

```
struct exemplo{
  int x;
  int b;
};

int main(){
   struct exemplo exemplo;
}
```

Quando declarei a variável `exemplo` na `main` o compilador aloca na *stack* tudo que está na `struct exemplo`. O certo não seria na variável `exemplo` alocar o tamanho da `struct`, que nesse caso nao seria 8 *bytes*?

E no caso de alocação dinâmica de memória, quando aloco um tipo `int` ela aloca 4 *bytes* de endereço, mas quando aloco uma `struct` são alocadas todas as variáveis da `struct`. Não teria que ser apenas o espaço da `struct` no ponteiro?

Answer (score 3):

O tamanho de alocação de uma estrutura não é algo tão simples, existe a questão do [alinhamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50614/101). Dependendo do compilador, das diretivas, do código e da plataforma que estiver rodando pode ser diferente mas há uma chance razoável que seja 8 *bytes* mesmo, só não conte com isto como se fosse certo. Isto pode ser descoberto pelo próprio [código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50614/101).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Exemplo { int x; int b; };

int main() {
    Exemplo exemplo;
    cout << "Tamanho de exemplo: " << sizeof(exemplo) << endl;
    cout << "Valor de exemplo.x: " << exemplo.x << endl;
    cout << "Valor de exemplo.b: " << exemplo.b << endl;
    Exemplo *exemplo2 = new Exemplo;
    cout << "Tamanho de exemplo2: " << sizeof(exemplo2) << endl;
    cout << "Tamanho do objeto apontado por exemplo2: " << sizeof(*exemplo2) << endl;
    cout << "Valor de exemplo2 (o ponteiro): " << exemplo2 << endl;
    cout << "Valor de exemplo2->x: " << exemplo2->x << endl;
    cout << "Valor de exemplo2->b: " << exemplo2->b << endl;
    cout << "Tamanho de exemplo2.x: " << sizeof(exemplo2->x) << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9656uw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lmtpmyue-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/AllocationSize.cpp).

A alocação dinâmica aloca a memória necessária para objeto que pretende alocar. Não importa se é na *stack* ou no *heap*, o tamanho deve ser o mesmo. No caso vai alocar espaço para um objeto, no seu exemplo ele teria 8 *bytes* e a variável vai receber o ponteiro para este objeto. O tamanho do ponteiro é fixo para a aplicação, todos ponteiros possuem o mesmo tamanho, o que varia é o tamanho do objeto que ele aponta. Ponteiro e o objeto que ele aponta são coisas distintas que possuem uma relação eventual. No caso o objeto que seria apontado deve ter 8 *bytes*, afinal seria a mesma estrutura.

Em um exemplo simples o objeto estaria no *heap* e o ponteiro alocado na variável estaria na *stack*. Mas nada impede que o ponteiro esteja no *heap* também basta o código preferir colocar lá por algum motivo.

Se quiser entender mais sobre ponteiro, tem uma [pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) aqui no site.

Comment: Vlw cara mais quero saber mesmo porque uma aloca so endereços de memoria e outra aloca as variaveis sendo que nao teria que ser apenas o tamanho?

Comment: Estou tentando entender o que você está falando mas está difícil. Procure ler com calma o que você escreve depois e veja se acha que está compreensível. Tudo o que você postou no site até agora é difícil de compreender. Talvez por isto você também não compreenda o que está escrito nas respostas. Nenhuma aloca endereços, muito menos só endereços e nenhuma aloca variáveis. Você leu todas as respostas que você recebeu aqui? Você leu os *links* apontados nas respostas? Você votou em apenas uma delas e não aceitou nenhuma resposta até agora, dê uma revisada nas suas perguntas e veja o [tour].

Comment: Se eu entendi o que você quis dizer, Alexsander, você acha que usando `malloc` o compilador aloca *"só endereços de memória"*, e fazendo declaração estática ele aloca *"as variáveis"*. Na verdade, como o @bigown já bem explicou, nas duas formas o compilador **sempre** aloca o espaço da estrutura (ou seja, "as variáveis"). Só que quando você usa `malloc` (e, consequentemente, faz a alocação no *heap*), o compilador aloca **também** um espaço de tamanho fixo para o ponteiro, que irá literalmente apontar para o espaço original onde estão "as variáveis".