# Por que o tamanho de uma struct não é a soma dos tamanhos de suas variáveis?

Tags: c, c++, memória, struct, padding

Por exemplo, o código a seguir:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct exemplo{
    char letra;
    int numero;
    float flutuante;
};

int main()
{
    printf("Tamanho do char: %u\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("Tamanho do int: %u\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("Tamanho do float: %u\n", sizeof(float));
    printf("Tamanho da struct: %u\n", sizeof(struct exemplo));
}
```

Mostra no console:

```
Tamanho do char: 1
Tamanho do int: 4
Tamanho do float: 4
Tamanho da struct: 12
```

Ou seja, o tamanho da struct é 12 e não 9 (1+4+4) como esperado.
Por que isso acontece?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na verdade, a estrutura pode ter o mesmo tamanho que a soma de seus membros. Depende do alinhamento. Se os membros permitem montar a estrutura de forma alinhada terá o mesmo tamanho.

O caso apresentado realmente obriga alinhar o tipo `char` para uma [palavra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)), então há um desperdício de espaço. Isso é chamado de [*padding*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50614/101). Os *bytes* usados para o *padding* não são usados, indicam nada. E não há problema algum nisso, é o normal. É feito assim por questões de performance. Na maioria dos casos o compilador sabe fazer melhor que o programador.

Se precisar de algo diferente pode ser resolvido com [`#pragma pack(1)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(v=vs.140).aspx) ou [`__attribute__((packed))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html). Mais informações podem ser obtidas na resposta *linkada* acima. Raramente isso é realmente necessário e é melhor não mexer nisto se não entender todas as implicações que terá.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu não diria que raramente é usada,se você vai transmitir dados por uma rede, por exemplo, será de suma importância saber como os dados estão dispostos na memória.

Comment: Sim, este é um caso, mas considere todas operações que se faz na memória de forma trivial e esta utilização. A desproporção é brutal, o que a faz rara. Claro que o raro não é no sentido de não se fazer, não precisa nunca, apenas que são poucas situações onde realmente é necessário, considerando tudo onde estruturas são usadas.

Comment: se "você vai trasnmitir dados por uma rede" - tem qu adotar um protocolo de seriaçização bem definido. Você pode selecioan r um dentre dezenas de protocolos existentes, ou criar o seu ad-hoc. Se optar por criar o seu, tem que saber de coisas como padding, e outras depêndencias que mudam o arranjo dos dados na memória - e é por isso que é melhor usar um conjunto de ferramentas já existentes, em geral com alguns meses ou anos de trabalho para saber de todos os corner cases, do que sair fazendo o seu na louca.