# Para que serve o ":" (dois pontos) na declaração de um membro de uma estrutura?

Tags: c, c++, struct, bit

Vi isto:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char a : 1;
    unsigned char b : 7;
} Tipo;
```

O que significa essa declaração? O que é esse 1 e 7?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vamos executar esse código para entender melhor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char a : 1;
    unsigned char b : 7;
} Tipo;

int main(void) {
    Tipo x = { .a = 1, .b = 64 };
    printf("%d e %d\n", x.a, x.b);
    printf("%zd\n", sizeof(Tipo));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/AUwXn2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xjujajoq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/BitFieldStruct.c).

Tente colocar no membro `a` um valor maior que 1. Não funciona, só pode ser 0 ou 1. Já pegou por que?

Na segunda impressão vemos que o tamanho desta estrutura é 1 byte. E agora, matou?

Os dois pontos são usados quando a estrutura é usada para montar uma cadeia de bits e cada membro é chamado de *bit field*. Então o que vem depois do `:` é a quantidade de bits que aquele membro contém. Por isso o `a` só pode ter 0 ou 1. Ele só tem 1 bit. O mesmo vale se tentar colocar mais que 127 em `b` que só tem 7 bits.

Idealmente essas estruturas deveria ter um tamanho total múltiplo de 8 para encaixar com um byte, mas se não tiver ocorrerá um [alinhamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50614/101) de acordo com regras do compilador.

Os tipos possíveis dos membros são especificados como `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int` e outros especificados pelo compilador, que é o que foi usado. Costuma ser melhor usar tipos com tamanho definido universalmente. Então é melhor um `int32_t` do que um `int`.

É muito comum que este tipo de estrutura esteja dentro de uma estrutura maior com outros membros.

Também é muito comum usar com [`union`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137393/101). Assim você pode acessar um membro da união como um dado único e o outro membro da união como uma estrutura de bits.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    char valor;
    struct {
        unsigned char a : 1;
        unsigned char b : 1;
        unsigned char c : 1;
        unsigned char d : 1;
        unsigned char e : 1;
        unsigned char f : 1;
        unsigned char g : 1;
        unsigned char : 1;
    } bits;
} Tipo;

int main(void) {
    Tipo x = { .valor = 87 };
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", x.bits.a, x.bits.b, x.bits.c, x.bits.d, x.bits.e, x.bits.f, x.bits.g);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/oVd9o0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iznuqwic-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/BitFieldUnion.c).

Note que mostrei mais um outro ponto. Você não é obrigado identificar todos os bits. Claro que não colocando um nome em algum bit, ou conjunto de bits, não poderá acessar seu valor de forma direta e nomeada.

Comment: Se um `char` possui o tamanho de 1 byte que vale 8 bits, como é possível definir 1 bit para uma variável de tipo `char` ? Já que, ela por padrão guarda 8 bits, que nesse caso é a quantidade de bits necessários para representar um símbolo (caractere).

Comment: @gato porque ali não é o tipo `unsigned char`, é o tipo `unsigned char : 1`, parece o mesmo tipo, mas não é :)

Comment: Também não compreendi esta linha `unsigned char : 1;` parece que vc declarou uma variável que não contem um nome, pelo menos um nome que o programador usaria para acessa-la, e na union `Tipo` vc acessou todas as variáveis com nomes por exemplo `x.bits.a`, e se eu quisesse acessar o valor da variável sem nome `unsigned char : 1;` da estrutura `bits`?

Comment: @gato naõ consegue. Obviamente que eu só fiz isso pra demonstrar, mas tem bastante utilidade, talvez não como o último. Esse tipo de técnica é muito usado para pegar partes de um número que querem dizer alguma coisa específica. Para compactar juntamos o máximo de informação possível em um número de algum tamanho, pode ser um número de 1 byte, 2, 4, etc. Cada bit ou conjunto de bits é um campo de informação independente. Mas pode ser que alguns não interessam pra sua aplicação, estão lá como alinhamento, ou reservados para uso futuro, não se sabe ainda pra que será usado.

Comment: Não tem porque dar nome ali, mas precisa declará-lo para dizer que tem esses bits no *layout*  do dado que será pego e ignorado pela aplicação. Você ainda consegue acessar esse trecho, mas não por um nome, mas em geral se não vai dar nome é porque não deve acessar. teria que fazer um "´calculo" através de deslocamento de bits e fórmulas que o envolva, como já falei alguma coisa em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175345/101 e muita gente não achou útil :D

Comment: Esta [estrutura](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f4000cd99750065d5177555c0a805c97174d1b9f/arch/s390/include/asm/sysinfo.h#L24) do Linux usa, mas não entendi qual é a finalidade rsrs.

Comment: @gato Não posso afirmar sem conhecer detalhes, mas é essencialmente uma reserva de espaço para uso futuro. Se prestar atenção tudo gera um alinhamento de 4 bytes, mesmo onde tem 5, em seguida tem 3, esse começo tinha 3 `char`s, então ficaria 1 byte sobrando, já que seria alocado de qualquer jeito, fez explicitamente http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125057/101