# Erro da função malloc: sysmalloc: Assertion failed em C

Tags: c, malloc

Estou implementando uma Red Black Tree em C, e quando vou alocar memória para o segundo nó, dá o erro:

> sysmalloc: Assertion [...] failed. Aborted (core dumped)

Já pesquisei sobre e imagino que quando aloco memória para o segundo nó o C acessa alguma área na memória que já está alocada, suponho que seja porque o tamanho da `struct` é relativamente grande (8 bytes). Segue o código:

```
//struct que define os nodes
struct node {
       int key;
       struct node * left;
       struct node * right;
       struct node * parent;
       char c;
};
typedef struct node Node;

//função que seta os valores do no e retorna
Node* setNode(Node* parent, int value){
      Node* new = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node*));
      new->key = value;
      new->parent = parent;
      new->left = NULL;
      new->right = NULL;
      new->c = 'R';
      return new;
}

Node* insert(Node* node, Node* parent, int key){
      //checks if node is root
      if (node == NULL){
          //printf("%d\n", key);
          node = setNode(parent, key);
          //root node is always black
          //printf("%d\n", key);
          node->c = 'B';
          return node;
      }

      if (key < node->key){
          printf("entro aqui\n");
          return insert(node->left, node, key);
      }

      else
          return insert(node->right, node, key);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está na linha em que você aloca memória para o nó, dentro da função `setNode()`:

```
Node* new = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node*));
```

Quando você usa `Node*` é o mesmo que dizer que você está usando "*um ponteiro para a estrutura Node*", e, em um sistema de 32-bit, um ponteiro tem somente 4 bytes. Só que você está usando esse tipo para verificar o tamanho da estrutura, chamando `sizeof(Node*)`, logo, nessa linha você na verdade está alocando apenas 4 bytes na memória, porque com essa instrução você está retornando o tamanho do ponteiro para a estrutura, e não o tamanho da estrutura de fato.

O correto é usar a própria estrutura na função `sizeof()`, 
sem o asterisco, porque aí sim você terá o tamanho necessário para armazenar toda a estrutura:

```
Node* new = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

E, corrigindo, a sua estrutura não tem só 8 bytes. Em um sistema de 32-bit, os tamanhos individuais dos campos seriam:

```
int key             -> 4 bytes
struct node* left   -> 4 bytes
struct node* right  -> 4 bytes
struct node* parent -> 4 bytes
char c              -> 1 byte
```

O que daria um total de 17 bytes, mas provavelmente o retorno de `sizeof(Node)` será 20 bytes porque é necessário fazer um [alinhamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125057/86952) (*padding*) do tamanho da estrutura.

Não se esqueça depois de desalocar a memória desses nós usando a função `free()` (mais sobre ela [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/86952)). Veja um exemplo de como liberar os nós de uma árvore binária:

> [algorithm - Deallocating binary-tree structure in C - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32733437/8133067)

Basicamente, o código que está no link é esse:

```
void freeTree(Node* node)
{
   if (node == NULL) return;
   freeTree(node->left);  
   freeTree(node->right);
   free(node);
}
```

É uma função recursiva. Você dispara ela passando o primeiro nó, o pai de todos, e ela segue chamando a si própria para os nós filhos até que chegue no fim, e volta liberando a memória alocada para a estrutura de cada nó, de trás para frente. Primeiro com o lado esquerdo, depois com o direito.

Portanto, precisa tomar cuidado para não ocorrer o estouro da pilha, o famoso *[stack overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/)*, que pode acontecer se a quantidade de nós for muito numerosa.

Comment: Achei bem interessante a menção ao alinhamento, que por muitas vezes passa despercebida, especialmente quando o elemento que estraga o alinhamento vem no fim.