# Qual a diferença entre os tipos de dados enum, struct e union em C?

Tags: c, struct, tipagem, sintaxe, enums

Eu estou lendo o [manual de C da GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Data-Types) e estou na seção de tipos de dados
e eu percebe uma certa semelhança entre os tipos `enum`, `struct`, e `union`. A sintaxe é a mesma, ou existe algo que difere entre elas? Em quais casos eu devo usar qual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apesar de terem sintaxes semelhantes suas funções são muito diferentes, a união é uma estrutura camaleoa, e uma enumeração possuem dados constantes.

## `struct`

Uma estrutura possui um conjunto de membros, ou seja, cada membro listado ali fará parte da estrutura, ela é aditiva. Seu tamanho é a soma dos membros mais o [alinhamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50614/101).

## `union`

Uma união possui um único dado entre uma variedade disponível entre seus membros, ou seja, só um membro será usado de fato, excluindo a possibilidade dos outros. Seu tamanho é o do maior membro, considerando o alinhamento. Ela é produtiva (é o produto dos membros).

Do exemplo do manual:

```
 union numbers {
     int i;
     float f;
 };
```

`numbers` é uma estrutura de união que **ou** terá um dado inteiro **ou** terá um dado com ponto flutuante. Depende de arquitetura, mas provavelmente ambos têm o mesmo tamanho (4 bytes, na maioria dos casos), então pode-se dizer que `numbers` terá 4 bytes (o certo é sempre usar [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) para descobrir).

A união é muito útil para "conversar" com o hardware já que este pode fornecer dados de diversos tipos. Essa é uma forma de dinamizar o dado. Então você pode ter um único dado que pode assumir várias formas (tipos), mas várias APIs a usam para facilitar a passagem de parâmetros ou dar flexibilidade.

Também é útil para criar um "tipo variável", semelhante ao que linguagens dinâmicas costumam ter. Alias esta é uma técnica interna que essas linguagens usam para suas próprias variáveis. É uma forma de polimorfismo. É comum a união estar dentro de uma estrutura com um outro membro indicando qual é o tipo que está sendo guardado naquele momento, isso é chamado [*tagged union*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Tem uma técnica que é usada para montar ou destrinchar um dado. Você pode, por exemplo montar uma `struct` com 4 membros do tipo `char` (1 byte portanto) e depois cria um `union` com 2 membros, um é essa `struct`, e outro é um `int`. Assim você pode colocar cada um dos bytes na `struct` e depois acessar o dado pelo membro que é um `int`, ele será visto como uma coisa. Se montou do jeito certo, formará um número válido. Um exemplo mais "correto":

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        int8_t a;
        int8_t b;
        int8_t c;
        int8_t d;
    };
    int32_t x;
} meu_tipo;

meu_tipo var;
var.a = 0xFF;
var.b = 0xC0; 
var.c = 0xA5;
var.d = 0x0F;
int32_t y = var.x;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/UnionCoersion.c).

É possível fazer isto até com bits em vez de bytes.

## [`enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum)

A enumeração é uma forma de utilizar dados constantes (resolvidos em tempo de compilação) que estão relacionados em um conjunto. O comportamento lembra um pouco a união. Um objeto desse tipo só terá apenas um valor, os outros são excludentes. Nele, em vez de ter um dado qualquer, o que é usado é o próprio membro que tem um valor fixo definido na própria estrutura dele.

Os dados de cada membro costuma ser uma sequência numérica e é possível fazer operações matemáticas com eles, mas é possível dar valores que deseja para cada membro. Se deixar o padrão o compilador considera uma sequência começando do 0.

Se não houver uma extensão do compilador o tipo de cada membro é sempre `int` e um valor pertencente a essa enumeração pode ser usado onde um `int` pode ser usado, dado a tipagem fraca de C.

Para muitos programadores essa é a melhor forma de usar constantes em C. Claro que depende do objetivo.

Há quem goste de usar os nomes em maiúsculo como ocorria com o `#define`, mas muitos programadores não fazem mais isto por não ter a mesma necessidade do passado.

```
enum Direcao {Norte, Sul, Leste, Oeste}; //Norte é 0 e Oeste é 3
enum Permissao {Ler = 1, Escrever = 2, Apagar = 4, Executar = 8}
int p = Ler | Escrever; //vale 3 indicando que estas duas permissões estão ativas
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Enum.c).

Comment: gostei do exemplo que voce fez com o enum :) mas eu estava dando uma lida novavemte parece que o union so funciona com tipos inteiros procede? @bigown

Comment: O `enum` sim, o `union` definitivamente não.

Comment: enum se asemelha com o dict do python hehe

Comment: Não, não dá para comparar os dois. Tem gente que tenta, mas é bem diferente. Claro que dá para usar o `dict` do Python para simular uma enumeração, mas tem várias diferenças entre eles. O oposto não é verdadeiro.

Comment: sao diferentes mas eu disse que parece por acessar os valores por indices

Comment: Acho que faltou mencionar que em C os valroes do Enum são processados em tempo de compilação - o código ojbeto gerado nem sabe que existiu um enum - só vêo valor inteiro.

Comment: (Exceto as marcações para depuração, claro)

Comment: @jsbueno é, não coloquei aqui porque tinha respondido isso pra ele pouco antes, vou ver se coloco aqui ou faço um *link*. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

***ENUM***

É bem diferente do restante, já que ele é uma lista de números com nomes mais fáceis de usar.

Por exemplo, você pode criar a lista com os dois tipos abaixo:

```
typedef enum 
{
    TIPO_NM = 0,  //numero
    TIPO_ST       //string
}TIPO_VARIAVEL
```

Então, você pode fazer um switch, por exemplo, tratando cada um dos casos do enum e lidando com os tipos recebidos adequadamente. O programa vai considerar o número 0 para o TIPO_NM e 1 para o TIPO_ST, sendo que fica mais fácil de ler o que cada um dos tipos significa por uma pessoa. Quanto mais tipos você tiver, mais importante é ter um enum.

***STRUCT***

É a palavra chave para estruturas de variáveis. Qualquer conjunto pode ser representado aqui.

Por exemplo, na estrutura abaixo é representada uma mensagem, imaginando que todas as mensagens de uma determinada comunicação sempre tenham 10 bytes de corpo da mensagem, um inteiro de crc e um long de chave que identifica a mensagem:

```
typedef struct
{
    char mensagem[10];
    int crc;
    long chave;
}Mensagem
```

***UNION***

Significa que na mesma estrutura, pode ser utilizado de um jeito ou de outro. Isso serve para economizar espaço e os bytes são interpretados de forma diferente em cada caso da union.

Por exemplo, se a struct acima for utilizada como union, pode ser que seja uma mensagem de números ou de string dependendo do long recebido. Então a interpretação seria diferente em cada caso, mas a mesma estrutura seria alimentada sempre que receber uma mensagem nova.