# Como uma "struct" é organizada na memória?

Tags: c, c++, struct, memória

Como funciona o acesso à `struct`? Eu posso colocar os membros na ordem que eu quiser? Como o compilador sabe que parte da memória deve acessar? Como ficaria isto?

```
struct {
   char ch1;
   short s;
   char ch2;
   long long ll;
   int i;
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um *array* é uma sequência de elementos de um determinado tipo, certo? O *array* é uma posição de memória onde terá o primeiro elemento (0), e depois vem outro elemento igual, e assim por diante.

Se o tipo do dado tiver 1 byte e o *array* tiver 10 elementos, ele ocupará 10 bytes, um atrás do outro, como se fosse uma coisa só.

Se o tipo tiver 4 bytes, o objeto completo terá 40 bytes.

Para navegar entre os elementos, quando acessar `var[5]`, onde armazena `int`s, na verdade está acessando `*(var + 5 * sizeof(int))`, então provavelmente (depende da plataforma) se `var` aponta para o endereço 100 da memória (hipoteticamente), esse acesso ocorrerá na posição 120 da memória (100 + 5 * 4).

Pois bem, uma `struct` é uma sequência de membros de tipos variados. Esses membros são dispostos um atrás do outro como ocorre no *array*, mas o tamanho de cada membro variará de acordo com seu tipo. Então o acesso de `var.ll` é acessado pelo endereço da variável, mais o tamanho de todos os membros anteriores. Nesse exemplo da pergunta seria `var + sizeof(ch1) + sizeof(s) + sizeof(ch2)`. Na verdade tem que considerar o [alinhamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50614/101) também. Então o mais correto é usar o operador [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) que dá o deslocamento correto de cada membro.

Para facilitar vamos alinhar melhor e ver como fica:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct {
    long long ll;
    int i;
    short s;
    char ch1;
    char ch2;
} Tipo; 
    
int main(void) {
    Tipo var = { .ll = 1000000000000, .i = 1000, .s = 10, .ch1 = 'a', .ch2 = 's' };
    printf("%lld\n", var.ll);
    printf("%i\n", var.i);
    printf("%d\n", var.s);
    printf("%c\n", var.ch1);
    printf("%c\n", var.ch2);
    printf("%lld\n", *((long long*)(((char*)&var) + offsetof(Tipo, ll))));
    printf("%i\n", *((int*)(((char*)&var) + offsetof(Tipo, i))));
    printf("%d\n", *((short*)(((char*)&var) + offsetof(Tipo, s))));
    printf("%c\n", *((char*)(((char*)&var) + offsetof(Tipo, ch1))));
    printf("%c\n", *((char*)(((char*)&var) + offsetof(Tipo, ch2))));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/t3Ef3F). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lmspfsbx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Struct.c).

A segunda sequência de *prints*  produz o mesmo resultado, mas fazendo aritmética na mão, que é muito mais complicado. Deixemos o compilador fazer pra gente.

Na mão está fazendo:

- pega endereço da variável `var`
- faz um *cast*  para transformar tudo em byte (`char *`) e poder manipular os bytes livremente
- descobre o deslocamento do membro e soma com o endereço da variável
- faz um *cast* para o tipo do membro
- pega o conteúdo do endereço achado

A beleza do C é justamente tratar tudo da forma mais concreta e simples possível. Entender é mais complicado do que a execução efetiva. Uma estrutura é só um mapa para endereços de memória.

Então nessa `struct` do exemplo o acesso seria:

```
typedef struct {
    long long ll; // na posição 0
    int i;       // na posição 8
    short s;     // na posição 12
    char ch1;    // na posição 14
    char ch2;    // na posição 15
} Tipo;
```