# Quais os benefícios de usar struct?

Tags: c, struct

Como que variáveis do tipo `struct` ficam alocadas na memória, por exemplo:

```
struct livro{
char autor[10];
float preco;
};

//como essas variaveis fica alocado na memória?
struct livro livro1;
strcpy(livro1.autor, "Deitel");
livro1.idade = 320.25;
```

Aliás, o conceito de `struct` é muito semelhante a orientação a objetos, ou é impressão minha?

O que acontece dentro da memória ao usar `struct`?

Comment: Struct e class são essencialmente a mesma coisa mudando apenas o nível de acessibilidade padrão dos membros. Struct tem como padrão public, class é private.

Comment: É [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/112052)? Sugiro que veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=diferen%C3%A7a+struct+class) também, tem bastante coisa sobre o assunto...

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Toda vez que quiser manter organizado dados diversos, provavelmente de tipos heterogêneos, agrupados de forma lógica como uma coisa só ela é útil. Existem casos que até um dado pode ser útil fazer assim como uma abstração.

Quando você declara uma `struct` está apenas mapeando como esses dados estão configurados na memória e você poderá acessar cada dado individual através dos nomes de seus membros. Ela só existe no código, durante a execução não existe nada que indique que aquilo é uma `struct`, apenas tem dados, um atrás do outro.

Se acha que isto é semelhante a orientação a objetos é porque não tem ideia do que é orientação a objetos. Mas não se preocupe, quase todo mundo programa assim, ou pensa que programa e também não sabe o que é. Juntar dados em uma estrutura única nunca foi orientação a objetos, mas realmente muitas pessoas acham que é isto. E ainda ela usa a notação de objeto (substantivo, ponto, adjetivo), aí confunde mais ainda.

De fato quando cria uma `struct` está criando um modelo de como um objeto será composto, assim como um `int` é um objeto composto por bits de uma certa forma que representa um número inteiro e tem um único membro acessado de forma direta para facilitar, ou seja, objeto sempre existiu em tudo e as pessoas acham que objeto é algo ligado à uma classe, não é, isto é um conceito universal independente de paradigma. Já respondi sobre isso em [Em programação, o que é um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101).

O resto eu já respondi em [Como uma "struct" é organizada na memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183287/101).

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo sua pergunta de uma maneira mais empírica, podemos recorrer ao utilitário **objdump**.  Usando sua struct como exemplo e compilando com a flag "-g" para fornecer informações de debug, obtemos:

```
<1><2e2>: número abbrev: 8 (DW_TAG_structure_type)
    <2e3>   DW_AT_name        : (cadeia indirecta, desvio: 0xed): livro
    <2e7>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 16
    <2e8>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <2e9>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 4
    <2ea>   DW_AT_decl_column : 8
    <2eb>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x30a>
 <2><2ef>: número abbrev: 9 (DW_TAG_member)
    <2f0>   DW_AT_name        : (cadeia indirecta, desvio: 0x18): autor
    <2f4>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <2f5>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 5
    <2f6>   DW_AT_decl_column : 6
    <2f7>   DW_AT_type        : <0x30a>
    <2fb>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 0
 <2><2fc>: número abbrev: 9 (DW_TAG_member)
    <2fd>   DW_AT_name        : (cadeia indirecta, desvio: 0xda): preco
    <301>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <302>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 6
    <303>   DW_AT_decl_column : 7
    <304>   DW_AT_type        : <0x31a>
    <308>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 12
```

Os parâmetros mais relevantes acima evidenciam as seguintes informações:

1. **DW_TAG_structure_type**, **DW_TAG_member** e **DW_AT_name** evidenciam os tipos das informações que estão sendo tratadas, sendo as mesmas a própria struct, seus campos e nomes respectivamente.
2. **DW_AT_byte_size**: Fornece o número em bytes usados pela struct.
3. **DW_AT_data_member_location**: Fornece a posição em bytes onde os dados de um campo se localizam. Aqui fica evidenciado o fenômeno de "padding" (bytes inseridos no meio do caminho) para alinhar os campos.