# Vetores e estruturas tem sempre endereços contínuos?

Tags: c, array, struct, memória

Por quê vetores e estruturas são contínuas em memória? Creio que não seja somente coincidência.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char s[10];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%d=%p.\n", i, (void*)&s[i]);
    struct {
        double r;
        int x;
        char str[4];
        int t;
    } E;
    printf("---------------\n");
    printf("& r     =%p.\n", & E.r);
    printf("& x     =%p.\n", & E.x);
    printf("& str[%d]=%p.\n",0, & E.str[0]);
    printf("& str[%d]=%p.\n",1, & E.str[1]);
    printf("& t     =%p.\n", & E.t);
    printf("---------------\n");
    printf("sizeof(double)=%d.\n", (int) sizeof(double));
    printf("sizeof(int)=%d.\n", (int) sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(char)=%d.\n", (int) sizeof(char));
}
```

Saída:

> ```
> 0=0x7ffe7531a1f2.
> 1=0x7ffe7531a1f3.
> 2=0x7ffe7531a1f4.
> 3=0x7ffe7531a1f5.
> 4=0x7ffe7531a1f6.
> 5=0x7ffe7531a1f7.
> 6=0x7ffe7531a1f8.
> 7=0x7ffe7531a1f9.
> 8=0x7ffe7531a1fa.
> 9=0x7ffe7531a1fb.
> ---------------
> & r     =0x7ffe7531a1d0.
> & x     =0x7ffe7531a1d8.
> & str[0]=0x7ffe7531a1dc.
> & str[1]=0x7ffe7531a1dd.
> & t     =0x7ffe7531a1e0.
> ---------------
> sizeof(double)=8.
> sizeof(int)=4.
> sizeof(char)=1.
> ```

Comment: Por que você acha que poderia ou deveria ser diferente?

Comment: Não acho. Mas evito usar ponteiros por não ter certeza que é contínuo. No caso de vetor de caracteres eu até uso, mas não tenho certeza se inteiros ou outros tipos (inclusive os definidos por typedef) funcionam da mesma forma. E eu não gosto de programar "achando".

Comment: No caso das structs os elementos que a compõe podem não ser alocados em posições contíguas devido ao alinhamento das posições de memória que o compilador utiliza de acordo com o tipo de dado, podendo existir posições de memória não utilizadas para manter tal alinhamento.

Comment: Em seu exemplo altere  char str[4]; para  char str[3]; e observe o endereço aonde será alocado o int t.

Comment: {dc=0, dd=1, de=2, df=3}=str[4], não entendi onde está o erro (e não me lembro de ter alterado algo que não seja a formatação nos Ctrl+c - Ctrl+v

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`struct`** é algo para você agrupar dados heterogêneos que seriam isolados para serem tratados como uma coisa só, é dar coesão a um tipo de objeto que você está criando, então qual o sentido de que eles estejam separados? Que ganhos espera ter com isso? São contínuos porque é justamente o que deseja, que tudo aquilo seja algo junto.

O mesmo vale para um ***array***, o objetivo dele é ter um conjunto de dados homogêneos que seriam isolados ficando como uma coisa só e que possa ser acessado com complexidade constante (O(1)) o que exige que a posição exata seja conseguida através de uma aritmética simples, o que impede que cada elemento esteja espalhado pela memória, mas isso é até mais consequência do motivo anterior.

Essa aritmética é o endereço de memória do elemento inicial mais a posição simples do elemento (índice) vezes o tamanho de cada objeto individual (por isso o objeto precisa ter o mesmo tamanho).

Em ambos você quer que aquilo seja um objeto só, então seria difícil que não fosse contínuo. Você não pode ter um terreno único com outros no meio, se tiver buracos você tem vários terrenos e não um só. As duas formas são maneiras de ter algo junto.

Isto tem consequências importantes para o que vai fazer depois por causa desta organização. Tenha certeza que essas formas existem justamente para ter tudo de forma continua. Não tenho fácil algo da especificação, mas posso te garantir que tem nela algo dizendo que isto é garantido para estes dois casos.

Como esses dados são sempre acessados por um ponteiro, mesmo que você [não veja isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101) (o membro da estrutura não exatamente um ponteiro dinâmico, mas de forma análoga que é resolvida já pelo compilador) pode confiar que acessará de forma adequada, embora para o caso da `struct` a aritmética da memória é feita de forma que você nem tem controle sobre a continuidade.

Claro que o acesso fora da região do objeto já não funciona direito.

[Isto pode ajudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183287/101).

## Um objeto contínuo é diferente de continuidade entre objetos

Se está falando de um objeto ter sido alocado depois do outro, isso é normal no *stack* já que os objetos são empilhados continuamente, novamente para ter uma performance muito boa ([leia mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)). Se estivesse alocando no *heap* seria quase coincidência. É verdade que a maioria dos casos ficarão seguidos, afinal em um caminhão quando você vai carregando vai colocando uma caixa lodo atrás da outra ou acima das outras de forma organizada, na memória é igual. Claro que você pode ter compartimentos e algumas coisas ficam um pouco fora de ordem, por isso nunca considere que alocação no *heap* terão dois objetos distintos logo em seguida (não confundir com membros ou elementos internos desse objeto, esses de alguma forma ficam contínuos, pelo menos na visão mais abstrata).

Note que nada garante que no *stack* um objeto será alocado em continuo a outro também, é bem mais comum, mas há alguns casos que isso pode não ser verdade em algumas implementações (desconheço uma que seja assim), por isso só confie na continuidade interna do objeto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).